# Error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '

Tags: python

How to read the file with the numbers and save it in the list?
I tried this way but i got the error: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`
I would be grateful for your help and apologize for the grammar mistake.

The code:

```
file = open("edges.txt", "r")
list1 = []
for x in file.readlines():
    list1.append([int(k) for k in x.rstrip("\n").split(" ")])
```

The content of my txt. file is:

```
1 2
3 5
2 4
4 6
```

It should look like:

```
[1, 2]
[3, 5]
[2, 4]
[4, 6]
```

Comment: Your file must have a blank line at the end.

Comment: @JohnGordon if this is the case, an if-statement can be added to the list-comprehension as follows: [int(k) for k in x.rstrip("\n").split(" ") if k.isdigit()]

Comment: @JohnGordon not only at the end of the line, any double space in the string will produce the same behavior

Answer (score 1):

Let's break it down, this:

```
list1.append([int(k) for k in x.rstrip("\n").split(" ")])
```

Is the equivalent of this:

```
list1 = []
for k in x.rstrip("\n").split(" "):
    list1.append(int(k))
```

As you can see, `k` is clearly a part of a string, and the error means that it isn't a number. Try this:

```
file = open("edges.txt", "r")
list1 = []
for x in file.readlines():
    list1.append([int(k) for k in x.rstrip("\n").split(" ") if k.isdigit()])
```

But in better practice:

```
with open("edges.txt", "r") as file:
    list1 = []
    for x in file.readlines():
        list1.append([int(k) for k in x.rstrip("\n").split(" ") if k.isdigit()])
```

Comment: Do you know maybe why I get a list with 2 two blank lists inside it? Thank you!               Code:  [[1, 2], [3, 5], [2, 4], [4, 6], [], []]

Comment: That means that there are 2 non-empty lines in `"edges.txt"` that have no integers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isdigit()` of a string to validate that you are trying to convert number to int and another `strip()` method will help in this case since it seems that one line containing a number with space before or after.

```
file = open("edges.txt", "r")
list1 = []
for x in file.readlines():
    list1.append([int(k) for k in x.rstrip("\n").strip().split(" ") if k.isdigit()])
```

Comment: Why `isalnum()` instead of `isdigit()`?

Comment: You are right `isdigit()` will fit better in this case tnx for that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `isalnum()` since you are trying to convert to an integrer